# What is the reason for interrupting the thread in the catch clause of InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I'm reading J. Bloch's Effective Java and now I'm at the section which explains about Concurrency. The writer has provided the following example (Some modifications were applied to make it simpler):

```
Runnable action;
//...
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    ready.countDown();
        try {
            start.await();
            action.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // <------- Here
        } finally {
            done.countDown();
        }
    }
});
```

It's not clear that why we interrupt the Thread that already was interrupted? Couldn't you get a little explanation about what kind of troubles we may run into if we omit such interrupting?

Comment: What explanation does the author give?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the thread's interrupted flag say in the catch? Maybe it was cleared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's right.

When an `InterruptedException` is thrown from a blocking method, the interrupt flag is cleared.

The right thing to do is to reset the interrupt flag (i.e. interrupt again) and stop running ASAP. Resetting the interrupt flag is necessary to let the executor (or any other calling code) know that the thread has been interrupted, and thus allow it to stop running.

Comment: Thanks much. But one clarification. __When an InterruptedException is thrown from a blocking method, the interrupt flag is cleared__ Is that standartized or ressetting the interrupted flag is just a "defensive programming"?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not guaranteed (especially given that anybody can throw an InterruptedException). But the JDK blocking methods all do that (still AFAIK). Semaphore and CountDownLatch, for example, explicitely document that behavior.

Comment: What if one swallows the InterruptedException?  start.await(); perhaps has thrown it, it anyways wont block the thread further, can it? Why do we have to stop running ASAP, hasn't it already stopped by being interrupted?

Comment: If one swallows the InterruptedException, then one prevents the thread from properly stopping. Stopping a thread needs collaboration for the thread being stopped. If this thread doesn't collaborate by swallowing InterruptedException, then things don't work the way they should anymore.

Comment: "Stopping a thread needs collaboration for the thread being stopped" - Can you please give some examples to better understand this?

Comment: The code in the OP's question is an example. You can't force a thread to stop. All you can do is ask it to stop by interrupting it. It's up to the code in the thread to regularly check if it has been interrupted, and to properly handle InterruptedException, in order to return from its run method ASAP (but potentially, after cleaning up what needs to be cleaned: closing streams, leaving objects in a coherent state, etc.).